# How does ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit relate to HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm wondering how does `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` relate to the HttpWebRequest.

Let's say I set the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10` and then I create 20 threads that all need to send a request to the same url. Will the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` limit only 10 threads to send their request, and once done allow the other 10?

Let's say the code looks something like that as an example:

```
void send() 
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
    for (i < 20; i++) 
        {
            Task.Run( () => {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(dmsUrl);
            ...
            Request.GetResponse();
        }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint(v=vs.110).aspx  this may help you understand what a ServicePoint is and how can manage it with a mix of settings, such as **DefaultConnectionLimit** and **MaxServicePointIdleTime**